# OwnCloud client cannot sync because "... Server certificate was missing commonName attribute in subject name"

Tags: ubuntu, owncloud

I've installed OwnCloud 7 on my Ubuntu server. The server is self-signed with SSL. When accessing it in the browser I receive the following 2 messages:

> The security certificate presented by this website was not issued by a
>   trusted certificate authority. The security certificate presented by
>   this website was issued for a different website's address.

But then I click on Continue to this website and everything works fine.

Now I want to use the windows client. I can connect to the server, but I cannot sync. It only shows the following error message:

> "... Server certificate was missing commonName attribute in subject
>   name"

I generated a new key file, made absolutely sure the commonName is filled in and configured apache2 to use this key file, but still I receive the same error in my owncloud client...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Create your SSL certificate again a do not forget fill Common Name or FQDN. In my case it was same like comment higher. I put IP address and it works.

1. create new ssl script - validation e.g. 365 days

   ```
   sudo openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.key -out /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.crt
   ```
2. fill all fields - here is COMMONNAME field - FQDN or IP
3. restart apache

   ```
   sudo service apache2 restart
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by changing the commonname attribute into the IP address I use to access my owncloud server.

I think the error message is a bit misleading, maybe the attribute was not correct, but it certainly was not "missing"...